# Magento Not able to locate response class

Tags: magento2, event-observer

I am creating a module to capture response on `controller_front_send_response_before` event.

In my observer file, I am getting both `request` and `response` object but I am not able to locate below class of `response` object:

> Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor

I am searching in `/magento root/vendor/magento/framework/App` directory.

Also, When I was trying to log response, I got only headers in log file. How can I get final content that will print on browser?

In onbserver file I have written following code:

> Ktpl\Logresponse\Observer\Response\Capture.php

```
namespace Ktpl\Logresponse\Observer\Response;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;

class Capture implements ObserverInterface
{
    private $logger;

    public function __construct(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer) {
        try {
            $response = $observer->getEvent()->getData('response');
            $this->logger->debug($response);
            $this->logger->debug(get_class($response));
        } catch(\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->critical($e);
        }
    }
}
```

Please share if anyone has any idea about this.

Comment: Refer useful to you http://blog.belvg.com/declaring-observers-in-magento-2-0.html

Comment: Thank you for this useful link -- but my observer is working fine. When I call get_class function for response object, it gives me this class:
`Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor`

and I'm not able to locate this class.

Comment: Also, how can I get final content from response object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the class `Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor` is generated by the ObjectManager.

You can find the class on your Server under `var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/Response/Http/Interceptor.php`

This class is responsible for executing all Plugins defined for `Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http`

So the Actual Response Object is still `Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http`, but the Interceptor class is injected as a wrapper for this.

Comment: Thanks for this very useful information. Can you please tell me in which file, object manager injects this Interceptor class as wrapper?

Also how can I get actual content from response object in my observer?

Comment: I did not find the location where the Interceptor is injected yet, but the Interceptors are generated here I think https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Code/Generator/Interceptor.php. You should be able to call $response->getContent()

Comment: in Developer Mode the replacement seems to happen here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/ObjectManager/Config/Developer.php#L64